# Will rebuilding a spatial index recalculate the feature extent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-index, extents

ArcGIS 10.3.1

ArcSDE 10.2.2

SQL Server 2012

I'm reading documentation on how to [Rebuild a spatial index](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/modifying-a-spatial-index.htm). Will rebuilding the spatial index automatically recalculate the feature extent of the feature class?

Comment: I doubt it. Please *edit* the question to specify the data source (FGDB, enterprise GDB,..., and if enterprise which exact database product), since that may make a difference.

Comment: "Exact database product" would include the version.

Comment: Have you tried removing some features at the edge of a map (e.g., HI and AK from a US dataset), and rebuilding the index?  Testing this is the only way to be sure.

Comment: @Vince I've tested some. The dataset is very large, 2.5 million records, and I would not want to create any locks since it's actively being used. I did run the Check Geometry tool - this returned a few hundred problem records (all self intersecting issues). However, I checked all of these and they were not even close to the edges of the feature extent. But before running spatial index test (and possibly creating locks while actively being used), I wanted to know if the feature extent will automatically recalculate, as a quick work around until the bad data is located.

Comment: There's no reason to run this test on a production layer.  All you need is the generalized US states from Data & Maps. Insert all, get envelope, delete two, reindex, get envelope.  Check Geometry result is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your link [Rebuild a spatial index](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/modifying-a-spatial-index.htm):

> Recalculate the spatial index and **feature class extent** on a Geometry
>   feature class in a database or geodatabase in Microsoft SQL Server.

This appears to be the case only on *SQL Server* databases, but as that's what you're using then it appears that the answer to your question is "Yes".